# Gallery using Ul LI float

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox, image-gallery

I have a Gallery view where i use UL LI element with float left to make it sit like a gallery in as many lines a needed based on the content. After the first line it seems to go hay wire as shown below. Looks like the problem is in Firefox on both MAC/Win7

[image]

Link: http://archangle.mink7.com/portfolios (footer Gallery)

```
<ul class="gallery">
                                      <li> <a href="#"> <img alt="video" src="/img/portfolios/video.jpg">   <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> </a> </li>
                                      <li> <a href="#"> <img alt="Concept Gallery" src="/img/portfolios/concept-gallery-2.jpg">   <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> </a> </li>
                                      <li> <a href="#"> <img alt="Concept Gallery" src="/img/portfolios/concept.jpg">   <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> </a> </li>
                                      <li> <a href="#"> <img alt="Residential Gallery" src="/img/portfolios/residential-gallery2.jpg">   <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> </a> </li>
                                      <li> <a href="#"> <img alt="Residential Gallery" src="/img/portfolios/residential-gallery-1.jpg">   <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> </a> </li>
                                      <li> <a href="#"> <img alt="Commercial Image" src="/img/portfolios/commercial-gallery-2.jpg">   <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span> </a> </li>
                                    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.comment-image, .gallery li, .post-small .image, .post-image, .portfolio-item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Seems good to me. Is that a problem only with IE?

Comment: sorry posted the code :D

Comment: @abhitalks i am facing the problem in MAC Firefox

Comment: checked in Win - Firfox same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The heights are inconsitenet in FireFox and therefore you are getting an orphan in that last row. Try adding this to your gallery li's:

```
.gallery li {
   float: left;
   width: 33%;
   height:100px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will force consistent height on your image containers (li's) and cut off any excess image height.

Comment: the image sizes are same. i tried that but still it doesnt get alright

Comment: I think your "img" tags are missing the "/>" at the end, so may also be causing a markup error in FirFox. I recreated your gallery in jsfiddle (missing the hovers, but the display is correct). This works for me in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/4dz6c/9/

Comment: The first image (`/img/portfolios/video.jpg`) has different dimensions than the other ones (391x350 vs. 390x349). Since you're using percentage widths/heights all over the place, this seems to lead to a some kind of rounding mismatch/error. Not sure if this is a Gecko or Webkit/Blink bug, i.e. what the spec says about this, but you might want to [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) anyway. So either follow @ezekielDFM suggestion the or make sure all images have actually the same dimensions.